# om - data not updating after ajax call

Tags: clojurescript, om

I have the following code and I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

```
(defn world-view [data owner opts]
  (reify
    om/IInitState
      (init-state [_]
        (om/update! data #(assoc % :world vec)))
    om/IWillMount
      (will-mount [_]
        (go (let [world (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))]
              (log (get-in world [9 9]))
              (om/update! data #(assoc % :world world)))))
    om/IRender
      (render [this]
        (log (get :world data))
        (apply dom/table nil
          (om/build-all row (:world data))))))
```

I am making a remote ajax call in `om/IWillMount` like this:

```
om/IWillMount
  (will-mount [_]
    (go (let [world (<! (get-world (:dimensions opts)))]
          (log (get-in world [9 9]))
          (om/update! data #(assoc % :world world)))))
```

I am expecting a 2d vector back from the remote call and this works because I can log elements of the array with

```
(log (get-in world [9 9]))
```

I am then using `om/update` to update the data structure.

But when render is called, the data does not appear to be updated, I can test this by trying to log the data structure

```
log (get :world data))
```

This logs nothing.

I can't see what I am doing wrong or why the data structure has not been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`om/update!`](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Documentation#update) sets the cursor to the given value, so you're basically assigning a function to your cursor. I believe you should use [`om/transact!`](https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Documentation#transact) instead.